# Help me understand a part of Java Language Specification

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm reading part 17.2.1 of Java language specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1

I won't copy a text, it's too long, but I would like to know, why for third step of sequence they're saying that

`If thread t was removed from m's wait set in step 2 due to an interrupt`

Thread couldn't get to step 2 it wasn't removed from wait set, because it written for the step 1:

`Thread t does not execute any further instructions until it has been removed from m's wait set`

Thus thread can't be removed from wait set in step 2 whatever it's due to, because it was already removed.

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug caused by mistake in updating from prior version JLS, [Third Edition 17.8.1 Wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.8.1), missing number of the list item.

Prior version JLS had the respective sequence listed **from 1 to 4, not from 1 to 3**:

> 1. Thread `t` is added to the wait set...
> 2. Thread `t` does not execute any further instructions until...
> 3. Thread `t` performs n lock actions....
> 4. If thread `t` was removed from `m`'s wait set in **step 2**...

As you may see, **step 2** in original version document refers to the part other than currently marked 2.

Compared to original version, [JLS Java SE 7 Edition 17.2.1. Wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1) has lost list number <sup>(likely lost `<li class="listitem">` in html)</sup> at the item *Thread `t` does not execute...*

As a result, whole sequence now lists from 1 to 3 and words "step 2" left unchanged from original version refer reader to wrong item that has been previously marked 3, not 2.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPQaT.png]

Answer (score 2):

That is probably just a typo and is meant to be step 1.

Typos happen even in large projects and where a lot of people work on it.

Comment: I believe it's the only reason, because logically no way what is written can be true.

Comment: ping this to the concurrency-interest group that Doug Lea runs, you'll get confirmation there.

Comment: I asked about it on the concurrency interest mailing list and they replied that hard copy of JLS contains additional  numbered point on "Thread t does not execute any further instructions". So step 2 that is referred to on step 3 (which is actually a step 4) is that step with a missing numbered point. So it's just a missed numbered point that caused a confusion.